# How can I place a pkcs signature using a RSA key in a transaction on a Block to put into Blockchain?

Tags: python, blockchain, signature, sha256, pycryptodome

I'm currently working on a very simple project of a blockchain, mostly to understand the concept better by implementing it.
I am using python do develop it so to implement a signature I used this function

```
def sign(self):
    key = RSA.import_key(open(self.sk_file).read())
    self.h = SHA256.new(self.message)
    self.signature = pkcs1_15.new(key).sign(self.h)
```

It can read the file just fine and create a signature and validate it with the public key I send, which looks like this when I print it out

```
b'\x97{\x9e\x137\xc9\xbe\xa7u\xb2\xf3\xaa+$\xcf:K\xb6B\xbb,\xb01...
```

The way that I create the block is by using this function

```
 def __init__(self, index, transactions, timestamp, previous_hash, nonce=0):
     """
     Constructor for the `Block` class.
     :param index: Unique ID of the block.
     :param transactions: List of transactions.
     :param timestamp: Time of generation of the block.
     :param previous_hash: Hash of the previous block in the chain which this block is part of.
     """
     self.index = index
     self.transactions = transactions
     self.timestamp = timestamp
     self.previous_hash = previous_hash  # Adding the previous hash field
     self.nonce = nonce

 def compute_hash(self):
     """
     Returns the hash of the block instance by first converting it
     into JSON string.
     """
     block_string = json.dumps(self.__dict__, sort_keys=True)
     print(block_string)
     return sha256(block_string.encode()).hexdigest()
```

At the time I only want one transaction on each block so the block looks something like this

```
{"index": 1, "nonce": 0, "previous_hash": "e51eee0fcc3637670fdb3669bfd927401baf2796b41f0440b619c480c726d8d2", "timestamp": 1591179898.3917656, "transactions": ["{\"owner\": \"testUser\", \"message\": \"46070d4bf934fb0d4b06d9e2c46e346944e322444900a435d7d9a95e6d7435f5\", \"signature\": \"test\"}"]}
```

As you can see the signature is a test string but I wanted to include it in the transaction.

If I try to put the signature directly to the JSON object I get a

```
Type error: Object of type Transaction is not JSON serializable
```

Whenever I try to decode the byte array of the signature to string to put into the JSON it tells me that the codec can't decode byte 0x95, I've tried ASCII, utf-8, latin1, etc. Is there a special one that I can use?

Do you have any suggestion to try to fix this issue? Even if I have to not use JSON it'll be fine.

If you want to check out the code I have it here: https://github.com/djguu/Blockchain_CD

Thank you for your help!

PS: I am using a code that I found on the internet to build the blockchain, for this pourpose it's fine, I will not be using that for profit of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this!

If I do:

```
binascii.hexlify(self.signature).decode('ascii')
```

I get a str value with I can transform back to a byte array and validade the signature using:

```
binascii.unhexlify(self.signature)
```

That way I can use the signature however I like.